# Regarding splunk query

Tags: splunk

I have some audio files in S3 bucket. I want to write a splunk query to find the top 500 audio files and categorize them by date and store them in a folder. Also I want to do it every night. What should be my query?

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like the following.

`index=audiofiles earliest=-1d@d | stats count by title`

The `earliest=1d@d` means you only want to look at the last day's worth of logs. The `stats` command counts the frequency of each song, by `title`. I am assuming that there is a `title` field in your data.

You would probably choose to schedule a search like this to run every night. Should you wish to save the results of this data, you would write this data into a summary index with a `collect` command, or write it out to a CSV with `outputcsv` command